# large text file processing error

Tags: c++

everyone.

The program as shown below isn't executed for large text file, for example, 30GB.

The program is for simply converting text file format.

Let me know how to solve the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include </usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int r,g,b;

    if(argc!=3)
    {
 fprintf(stderr,"Usage:%s\n(1)Input_XYZRGB_filename\n(2)Output_PCD_filename\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }


    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    std::string buf;

    for(size_t i=0; ifs && getline(ifs, buf); i++)
    {

           // std::cout << buf << std::endl;
            std::istringstream is(buf);

            pcl::PointXYZRGB pnt;
            is >> pnt.x
            >> pnt.y
            >> pnt.z
            >> r
            >> g
            >> b;
            pnt.r= (uint8_t)r;
            pnt.g= (uint8_t)g;
            pnt.b= (uint8_t)b;
            cloud->push_back ( pnt );
    }
    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII(argv[2], *cloud);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Please be more specific.

Comment: My first bet is you're running out of RAM - the key is to process very large files as streams and be very careful with things like file pointers that could overflow your data types. Really though, "it does't work" is a terrible problem description.

Comment: So, you are reading a 30GB file into memory, and then storing it before writing back out to a new file? How much memory does your machine have - I expect that you need at least 10-15GB to store the data in a binary form.

Comment: The error message is "segmentation fault".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your file input/output library supports large files. You can read the documentation. Also check the size of the file position parameter in the seek operation. In order to support large files it has to be 64 bit, not 32. In MS Visual C++, standard iostream seems does not support large files. But you can use other, low level input/output functions: _sopen_s, _read, _close, _lseeki64, etc. In gcc and mingw, you can use functions: _sopen, read, close, lseek.